# Android Custom Camera Application Crash when open the camera

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to develop a custom camera application for my app. In few models(eg. Xiomi Red mi,Samsung core2 duos) it is giving problem when camera application started and it got crashed.

**MY Activity:**

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

        private Camera mCamera;
        private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
        static Context mcontext;

        List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
        private String meetingImgName="";
        private ArrayList<Promoter> promoterList = null; 
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_activity);

            Bundle mBundle =getIntent().getExtras();
            promoterList = (ArrayList<Promoter>) mBundle
                    .getSerializable("PromoterList");
            mcontext=this;
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();

            /*List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
            for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
            {
                if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
                    size = sizes.get(i);
            }
            params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);*/

            mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
          //Adding listener
            ImageView captureButton = (ImageView) findViewById(id.button_capture);
            ImageView cancelButton=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);

            captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try{
                            List<String> supportedFocusModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFocusModes();
                            boolean hasAutoFocus = supportedFocusModes != null && supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                            if(hasAutoFocus){
                            mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                      mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture);              
                                }
                            });
                            }else{
                                 mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, mPicture); 
                            }
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Helper method to access the camera returns null if
         * it cannot get the camera or does not exist
         * @return
         */
        private Camera getCameraInstance() {
            Camera camera = null;

            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // cannot get camera or does not exist
            }
            return camera;
        }
        ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onShutter() {
                AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
            }
        };
        PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {



             File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
                if (pictureFile == null){
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }



            }

        };
    ................................
.........................

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
              super.onResume();

              if (mCamera == null) {
                try {
                  mCamera = Camera.open();              
                  mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder());
                  mCamera.startPreview();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Unable to open camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();
                }
              }
            }
    }
```

**Preview Class:**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private boolean previewing = false;
    private Context mcon;
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mcon = context;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this); // we get notified when
                                                // underlying surface is created
                                                // and destroyed
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // this is adeprecated method, is not requierd after 3.0
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters()
                    .getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
            params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
            params.setExposureCompensation(0);
            params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            params.setJpegQuality(100);
            List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
            if (focusModes
                    .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                Toast.makeText(mcon, "auto focus supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Log.i("auto focus supported", "auto focus");
                // set the focus mode
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                // set Camera parameters        
            } else {
                Log.i("auto focus not supported", "Not supported");
                Toast.makeText(mcon, " auto focus not supported",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            previewing = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
                widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
                heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width,
                    height);
        }
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        if (previewing) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width,
                        mPreviewSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // intentionally left blank for a test
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the crash log cat:

[image]

what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Please try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832372/surfacecreated-java-lang-nullpointerexception

Comment: Check if the camera parameters (flash mode, focus mode , scene mode etc) that you are setting in the preview class are available in the  device models you are testing on.

Comment: it is working on all other phone only these device it is not working..

Comment: In Red mi 1s flash is present.

Comment: It says it's crashing on line 44, in surfaceCreated().  Which line of code is line 44?  Which variable is null?

Comment: Line no 44 mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder); and even i have tried if(mCamera !=null) then  mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);. In both case crashed.